# Determinging whether a select is open or not with Selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

For a test I am doing I have to verify that when you click on a dropdown, it opens,  And when you click again, it closes.

I have

<**select** id="pt1:r1:0:pt1:s1:r1:notesView:selTof::content" name="pt1:r1:0:pt1:s1:r1:notesView:selTof" style="width:150.0px;" class="af_selectOneChoice_content" title="Review Notes">

<option value="0" selected="" title="Review Notes">Review Notes</option>

<option value="1" title="Service Notes">Service Notes</option>

<select>

So I can get an xpath "//select/option" and do a find and see if it is found, and see whether it is displayed.  The problem is, whether or not the select box is clicked, the options are displayed.  Also I try to find the element (call it ele), and do a ele.click(); and catch an error if it could not be clicked.  But you can click it even if the menu is not expanded.

So is there another way to check?  I don't see any different attributes in the select.

(by the way, doing this with Java 1.8 and Chrome)

Comment: Interesting question! I don't see any way of doing with plain HTML select elements. There is no change in visibility, no change in CSS attributes when the select is open or closed :(

Comment: I guess I could take a screenshot and have a human look ;-)